# How do I declare my select query in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, declare

I want to declare a select query to use it in a trigger but I am a noob in sql in general :P Can somebody help me?

My code (example):

```
DECLARE Primary_Keys VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
SELECT cons.constraint_type 
FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols 
WHERE cols.owner = 'DAB_NAME' 
AND cons.constraint_type = 'P' 
AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name 
AND cons.owner = cols.owner;
END;
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it inside the trigger? There are better ways to do things than storing the query in a variable.

Comment: My task is to create a funtion/trigger (doesn't matter what it is as long as it works I am trying it with a trigger)  which adds a value to a primary key if I try to merge two databases together in which the primary keys are the same. I am trying to solve the task by selecting all pks inside a table via the constraint_table and just count them up by a random value.

Comment: A better solution to the actual problem you're trying to solve would be to have a new sequence in your merged database and overwrite the original primary keys. You may need to record the original primary key and new primary in an audit table (depends on your whole requirement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a *PROCEDURE* composed of *BULK COLLECT* with *FORALL* :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_list_constraints(
                              i_owner IN all_cons_columns.owner%TYPE
                              ) 
IS
BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Constraint Types for '||i_owner);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('------------------------------- ');
   FOR constraint_rec
      IN (SELECT distinct cons.constraint_type 
            FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols 
           WHERE cols.owner = i_owner --'DAB_NAME' 
           --AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
             AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name 
             AND cons.owner = cols.owner)
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(constraint_rec.constraint_type);
   END LOOP;
END;
/
SQL> var p_owner varchar2(50);
SQL> exec pr_list_constraints(:p_owner);

 Constraint Types for DAB_NAME 
 -------------------------------
 R
 U
 P
 C
```

P.S. Using a DB trigger is irrelevant for such type of tasks.

Comment: If I try to execute your procedure the following errors occur:                Fehlerbericht -
ORA-06550: Zeile 7, Spalte 39:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL-Befehl wurde nicht korrekt beendet
ORA-06550: Zeile 5, Spalte 11:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: @AnSuS excuse me, I forgot to add `CREATE OR REPLACE` before `PROCEDURE`. Now, that's OK. Please try again.

Comment: Thank you the procedure work fine! But the command: exec pr_list_constraints(:p_owner); gives our the error: missing defines

Comment: @AnSuS you're welcome. Did you define p_owner by `var p_owner varchar2(50);`?

Comment: @AnSuS just after defining p_owner issue `exec pr_list_constraints(:p_owner);`  or alternatively issue `exec pr_list_constraints('DAB_NAME');` directly.